# What's the best method to load html/texts inside a sliding div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to do. I want to create a sort of slide show effect on the main content. If the user click on the right or left arrow on this div, it will move forward/backward to the next "slide/text". The content inside this div or slide includes image, texts, hyperlinks, and can be styled by CSS. My question is, what's the best route to create this effect? I do not want to use flash. I am thinking of a combination of HTML5, CSS3, and jQuery and/or javascript. Does anyone have or know of examples similar to what I've described? Your suggestions or opinions are much appreciated.

Comment: Check out [bxslider](http://bxslider.com). It uses CSS3 if supported, else js to slide (or fadeIn) any html.

Answer (score 1):

There is lot of slide show scripts available, you can also try this

```
            <div class="mosaic-slide" style="z-index: 10;">

                <!-- The mosaic-slide div and the tiles are generated by jQuery -->
                <div class="tile" style="..."></div>
                <div class="tile" style="..."></div>
                <div class="tile" style="..."></div>
                <div class="tile" style="..."></div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

css:

```
        #mosaic-slideshow{
            /* The slideshow container div */
            height:500px;
            margin:0 auto;
            position:relative;
            width:670px;
        }

        .mosaic-slide{
            /* This class is shared between all the slides */
            left:80px;
            position:absolute;
            top:25px;

            border:10px solid #555;

            /* CSS3 rounded corners */
            -moz-border-radius:20px;
            -webkit-border-radius:20px;
            border-radius:20px;
        }

        .tile{
            /* The individual tiles */
            height:60px;
            width:60px;
            float:left;
            border:1px solid #555;
            border-width:0 1px 1px 0;
            background-color:#555;
        }
```

Demo:  http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/mosaic-slideshow-jquery-css/demo.html

Comment: Many thanks for the respons. However, as I looked at the demo, it seems this demo is for loading images only. I need to load and .html file inside of that slide OR the slide show should not be only images but images, texts, and hyperlinks. Can this be done with the current demo by loading .html instead of .png files?